# Reset values from jQuery Mobile

Tags: forms, input, checkbox, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I need to reset all the values ​​of field elements of my page. The elements are: inputs, selects (combobox), checkbox and radio group.
Searching found the following code:

```
$("*").attr('value', '');
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",false); 

$('select').each(function() {
    if($(this).children().length > 0) {
        $($(this).children()[0]).attr('selected', 'selected');
        $(this).change();
    }
});
```

Inputs and checkbox are ok with this code, but the other components present problems with the codes tested. The radio group needed or take any kind of selection or at least select the first. The combobox resets with this code but when trying to select a new value it is not storing your value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non textual inputs need to be refreshed. Here's an example of doing so:

```
//reset text input values, then refresh slider widgets
$(".ui-input-text").val('').filter('.ui-slider-input').slider('refresh');

//reset checkboxes and radio inputs, then refresh them
$(".ui-checkbox input[type='checkbox'], .ui-radio input[type='radio']").prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh"); 

//reset all select menus and then refresh them
$('.ui-select select').val('').selectmenu('refresh');
return false;
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MLewd/1/

Comment: Hello friend!
Thank you for helping me!
However, your code is having the same problem I had ... Everything is ok now resenting. But when trying to select a new item on any radio and select to put an alert to check its value, the value is "lost."
http://jsfiddle.net/MLewd/15/

Comment: Sorry friend after some more tests here worked exactly your code though, if I try to use an alert to check. Val () or select the radio returns me "undefined". But somehow the selected values ​​are there. Very strange!